# fscanf in C not reading full lines?

Tags: c, newline, scanf

This is so stupidly simple but I'm just having issues with it.

A text file has a header,

e.g.,

```
# Avizo BINARY-LITTLE-ENDIAN 2.1

define Lattice 496 384 470

Parameters {
    AlignTransform {
        slice0000 0 -0 -30 -1,
        slice0001 0 -0 -30 -1,
        slice0002 0 -0 -30 -1,
```

And I'm trying to read each of these lines using fscanf.

```
   int i;
   for (  i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
     fscanf(fp, "%s\n", buf);  
     printf("%d) %s\n",i,buf);
   }
```

resulting in this

```
0) #
1) Avizo
2) BINARY-LITTLE-ENDIAN
3) 2.1
4) define
5) Lattice
6) 496
7) 384
8) 470
9) Parameters
```

So it's parsing the whitespace instead of newlines. Not sure what's happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `%s` specifier in `fscanf` reads words, so it stops when reaching a space.

Use [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/) to read a whole line.

Comment: Ended up using fgets instead.

Answer (score 10):

I recommend that you use `fgets`, but if you insist on using `fscanf`:

```
fscanf(fd, "%[^\n]\n", buff);
```

This will read a full line.

Answer (score 1):

Although %s may mean "string", but fscanf (as scanf) is not a greedy mathing one, you should tell it the seperator is "new line".
And, You'd better to set maxinum buffer size to prevent buffer overflow.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NAME_MAX    80
#define NAME_MAX_S "80"

int main(void)
{
    static char name[NAME_MAX + 1]; // + 1 because of null
    if(scanf("%" NAME_MAX_S "[^\n]", name) != 1)
    {
        fputs("io error or premature end of line\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Hello %s. Nice to meet you.\n", name);
}
```