# Reading values from CSV file into variables

Tags: c, file-io, input, scanf

I am trying to write a simple piece of code to read values from a CSV file with a max of 100 entries into an array of structs.

Example of a line of the CSV file:

1,Mr,James,Quigley,Director,200000,0

I use the following code to read in the values, but when I print out the values they are incorrect

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) /*just assuming number of entries here to demonstrate problem*/
    {
    fscanf(f, "%d,%s,%s,%s,%s,%d,%d", &inArray[i].ID, inArray[i].salutation, inArray[i].firstName, inArray[i].surName, inArray[i].position, &inArray[i].sal, &inArray[i].deleted);
    }
```

Then when I print out the first name, the values are all assigned to the first name:

```
for(j = 0; j < 3; j++) /* test by printing values*/
    {
    printf("Employee name is %s\n", inArray[j].firstName);
    }
```

Gives `ames,Quigley,Director,200000,0` and so on in that way. I am sure it's how i format the fscanf line but I can't get it to work.

Here is my struct I'm reading into:

```
typedef struct Employee
    {
    int ID;
    char salutation[4];
    char firstName[21];
    char surName[31];
    char position[16];
    int sal;
    int deleted;
    } Employee;
```

Comment: `%s` is greedy, I think, and it reads a full word... It finds the `%d`, the integer part, then the `,`, and then it has to read a string. `,` is valid in a string, so it reads until the end of the line (there is no space until then), not until the first comma... And the rest remains empty. [(From this answer)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10477583/1667004)

Comment: You've got a firstN and a firstName in the posting - which is it? Can you post the struct as well?

Comment: Corrected the var name and added struct

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is because a string `%s` can contain the comma, so it gets scanned into the first string. There's no "look-ahead" in the `scanf()` formatting specifier, the fact that the `%s` is followed by a comma in the format specification string means nothing.

Use character groups (search [the manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) for <kbd>[</kbd>).

```
const int got = fscanf(f, "%d,%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%d,%d", &inArray[i].ID,
                       inArray[i].salutation, inArray[i].firstName,
                       inArray[i].surName, inArray[i].position, &inArray[i].sal, 
                       &inArray[i].deleted);
```

And learn to *check the return value*, since I/O calls can fail! Don't depend on the data being valid unless `got` is 7.

To make your program read the entire file (multiple records, i.e. lines), I would recommend loading entire lines into a (large) fixed-size buffer with `fgets()`, then using `sscanf()` on that buffer to parse out the column values. That is much easier and will ensure that you really do scan separate lines, calling `fscanf()` in a loop will not, since to `fscanf()` a linefeed is just whitespace.

Comment: So what you're saying at the end is that I should put this in a while loop while got = 7?

Comment: @user2368481 Actually no, I added more text.

Answer (score 2):

Might as well post my comment as an answer:

`%s` reads a full word by default.

It finds the `%d`, the integer part, then the `,`, and then it has to read a string. `,` is considered valid in a word (it is not a whitespace), so it reads until the end of the line (there is no whitespace until then), not until the first comma... And the rest remains empty. [(From this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10477583/1667004)

You have to change the separator with specifying a regex:

```
fscanf(f, "%d,%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%d,%d", &inArray[i].ID, inArray[i].salutation, inArray[i].firstName, inArray[i].surName, inArray[i].position, &inArray[i].sal, &inArray[i].deleted);
```

Instead of `%s`, use `%[^,]`, which means "grab all chars, and stop when found a `,`".

**EDIT**

`%[^,]s` is bad, it would need a literal `s` after the end of the scanset... Thanks @MichaelPotter

(From [Changing the scanf() delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885628/changing-the-scanf-delimiter) and [Reading values from CSV file into variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737117/reading-values-from-csv-file-into-variables/18737367?noredirect=1#comment40678906_18737367) )

Comment: The s should be removed because the [^,] acts as the specifier. That is: "%[^,]s" should be "%[^,]".  As it is coded, scanf will be looking for an s at the end of each field.  Failing to find the s, scanf will give up parsing.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelPotter brains switch off sometimes... This is exactly why pair programming can be a huge boost...