# Error when parsing line of CSV text

Tags: c, csv, ansi-c

I fail parsing a CSV file in C. I need to file a struct with data from that file. This is the relevant part of my structure:

```
typedef struct Info {
    /* Some strings, integers, etc. */
    char correct; /* This is the value I can't set */
    short int status;
} t_info;
```

One line from my file looks like this **xxxxxx;xxxxxxx;xxxxxxx;D;254** (the **D** is my problem, see below).

```
    char line[1024]; /* Buffer */
    t_info info;

    fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp);

    strcpy(info.xxxxxx, getLine(line, 1)); /* Works */
    strcpy(info.xxxxxx, getLine(line, 2)); /* Works */
    strcpy(info.xxxxxx, getLine(line, 3)); /* Works */
    strcpy(info.correct, getLine(line, 4)); /* Crashs! */
```

The getLine() function is taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911299/read-csv-file-in-c) post:

```
const char *getLine(char *line, int num)
{
    const char *tok, *tmp = strdup(line);

    for (tok = strtok(tmp, ";"); tok && *tok; tok = strtok(NULL, ";\n"))
    {
        if (!--num)
            return tok;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

What is my problem?

Comment: Haven't studied this in-depthly - what if you replaced D with DD. Does it work? Maybe it fails for one char; some edge case.

Comment: No, doesn't change anything.

Comment: Your solution is very sloppy: the memory allocated by `strdup()` cannot be freed because there is no way to figure the address of the start of the allocated block from the pointer returned by `getLine()`.  Furthermore, you do not test for `getLine()` failure, or even `fgets()` failure at end of file: a line with missing fields will cause undefined behavior.  As a matter of fact, a line with long fields will also cause undefined behavior.  More work needed!

Comment: Thanks for the input :) Will look into that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can not save into a `char` using `strcpy()`.

```
typedef struct Info {
    char correct; /* This is the value I can't set */
} t_info;

strcpy(info.correct, getLine(line, 4)); /* Crashs! */
```

Use

```
info.correct = *getLine(line, 4);
```

---

Your compiler *should* have warned about this.  Review compiler settings.

Comment: Interesting, no warnings and neither does your solution work. When debugging, the return value is in fact 'D', but somehow the strcpy-operation fails.

Comment: @LuMa The return value from `const char *getLine(char *line, int num)` cannot be `'D'`. `'D'` is  integer/char.  `getLine()` returns a pointer.  Anyways it is not about what `getLine()` returns.  It is about the destination for `strcpy()`.  `info.correct` has room for only a `char`.  `strcpy()` expects a pointer to an array in which to store many `char`.

Comment: @LuMa  Unclear is "neither does your solution work." and "somehow the strcpy-operation fails" as the answer should use `info.correct = *getLine(line, 4);` **instead** of `strcpy(info.correct, getLine(line, 4));`

Comment: Yes, sorry. You are right. What I wanted to say is, the function doesn't return NULL, it is in fact returning a "valid" value/pointer.

Comment: THANKS! You saved my day. I was just to tired to read your answer correctly :) Thanks again!

Comment: I just added a * to my existing code which wasn't your suggestion. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to fix this would be to get the first character of the line, and use that for the char.

```
info.correct = getLine(line, 4)[0];
```

Perhaps sscanf might be more suitable for your application [(guide here)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/38335) or [(similar answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18737294/5699206).

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work :/ But I will take a look into sscanf. I tried fscanf but failed because I read a string which contained spaces, which made my fscanf attempt fail.

Comment: No. The return value from the function is in fact 'D', but somehow the strcpy-function fails.