# Reading lines from CSV file and separating into values (sscanf SIGSEGV)

Tags: c, scanf

I have been working on a program that wants to read 10 lines from a csv file and separate the name and the grade. I have used the documentation provided here [Reading values from CSV file into variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737117/reading-values-from-csv-file-into-variables)

Unfortunately, my code throws a `SIGSEGV` when coming to the line with the `sscanf` statement. I have tried to remove the `,` between `%[^,]` and `%f`, after which it works but only gets the names, not the grades, which defeats the purpose.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char str[10][30], names[10][20];
    FILE *fp;
    int i; 
    float grades[10];

    fp = fopen("names.txt", "rt");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        fgets(str[i], 30, fp);
        sscanf(str[i], "%[^,], %f", &names[i], grades[i]);
        printf("%s ", names[i]);
        printf("%f ", grades[i]);
    };
}
```

This is the content of the csv file:

```
Bob,8
Carla,7
Jack,5
Julie,3
Goncalo,9
Vera,6
Jesse,8
James,8
Francis,10
Monica,6
```

Thank you for your help, if you need any other information please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: It worked, but why is the ampersand not necessary here? While in the other thread it was there?

Comment: I see, thank you for the quick answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments to your `sscanf` are incorrect, its should be:

```
sscanf(str[i], "%19[^,], %f", names[i], &grades[i]);
```

`names[i]` is a `char` array, so you should not pass its address, but the address of its first element, which is either `&names[i][0]` or simply `names[i]`.

Conversely, `grades[i]` is a `float`.  You must pass its address as `&grades[i]` or possibly `grades + i`, but it is less readable.

And you should check the return value to verify in the input string was correctly converted.

Also remove the extra `;` at the end of the `for` block.